# What forms of identification can I use if I don't have a credit / debit card on the Deutsche Bahn if passports aren't allowed?

Tags: trains, germany, paperwork

I will be traveling on my own to Germany in a few days, and will take the train on Deutsche Bahn.

I am 17, and have no credit cards, debit cards, etc. My parents will be booking the journey in advance with their credit card. I just have no idea what valid ID I could use that falls under the requirements, especially if passports aren’t allowed.

Comment: I assume your parents would not be completely comfortable with that solution but I think carrying their credit card with you should work in practice.

Comment: Related question: [Can friends use my DB online ticket if I hand them my credit card?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/47433/3089)

Comment: I also assume that for some reason "get a prepaid card" isn't a valid solution? Here in Italy you can literally get one in minutes.